# Creating a custom bot rather than using Hubot with Firebase

Tags: firebase, bots, hubot

I want to connect a custom Hubot to my Firebase database in my app, unfortunately, Firebase does not have an adapter to connect my Hubot implementation to. I will be making custom scripts and not really using any community scripts. Does it make sense to try and scrape together some type of adapter for Firebase or should I create a custom bot myself that directly connects to my Firebase database without Hubot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I decided Hubot's value can greatly be attributed to the large community backing it and the ease to create new scripts. I decided to write my own bot because I would only be writing my own scripts for it to use.

Comment: Hi!, I'm trying to create a web app that triggers when a change in a specific user value change and then send a notification through GCM to the user. But this is supposed to happen automatically. I saw your post about making a bot, I think that's a great idea and would help me a lot.

Could you help me pointing the way of how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much depends on how much of the Hubot ecosystem you want to reuse. If you are interested in reusing scripts and getting updates as the core is modified, create an adapter. If you don't care and don't want to learn how to build an adapter, hack together whatever you want in a fork.

Overall, I would recommend [building an adapter](https://hubot.github.com/docs/adapters/development/) and releasing it for others with similar needs.